# Search engine in android with database

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse, android-activity

Please help everyone, this is for our thesis and I want to have a search engine that get its variable into database.

Here's our code:

**all_books.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
   >
    <!-- Main ListView 
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/allbooks"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the java file and php code:

**AllBooksActivity.java**

```
public class AllBooksActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_get_all_books = "http://192.168.0.190/android_connect/get_all_books.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_ADD_BOOK_RECORDS_COPY = "add_book_records_copy";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray add_book_records_copy = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_books);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllBooks().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditBooksActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllBooks extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllBooksActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading books. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All books from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_all_books, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Books: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Books
                    add_book_records_copy = json
                            .getJSONArray(TAG_ADD_BOOK_RECORDS_COPY);

                    // looping through All Books
                    for (int i = 0; i < add_book_records_copy.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = add_book_records_copy.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewBooksActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllBooksActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_TITLE }, new int[] { R.id.pid,
                                    R.id.title });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

**get_all_books.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM add_book_records_copy") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["add_book_records_copy"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $add_book_records_copy = array();
        $add_book_records_copy["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $add_book_records_copy["title"] = $row["title"];
        $add_book_records_copy["authors"] = $row["authors"];
        $add_book_records_copy["subject"] = $row["subject"];
        $add_book_records_copy["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $add_book_records_copy["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];



        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["add_book_records_copy"], $add_book_records_copy);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**db_config.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * All database connection variables
 */

define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', "admin1"); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "androidhive"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "192.168.0.164"); // db server
?>
```

**db_connect.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

Please, try to suggest an search engine based on database, if you have any idea how to place it and make a code on it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently working on a thesis similar to yours. Essentially, it's the same.
A document search engine.

I would not recomment doing the search on a relational database. This is because it will not be efficient and will generate too much false positives. Also, it does not have support for contextual phrases and it's too coupled with the data's structure.

Here is the approach I'm currently using on my thesis:

- I will have two databases. One will be **relational** (SQL), and the other will be ***document oriented*** (NoSQL)
- Each database will be accessed and manipulated by two different ***web services***
- I am storing all my data in the relational database, and every once in a while indexing my "**searchable**" data into the documental one.
- Whenever I want to **retrieve information** I will use the relational database's web service. Whenever I want to **search information**, I will use the non-relational database's web service.

Please note, that the non-relational database will **only contain** the documents (or data) you actually want to get searched. Other persisted information should be in the relational database.

On summary, relational databases are efficient at **retrieving, inserting and deleting** information, while non relational databases are efficent at **searching** information.

Please, take a look at the following **text search engines**. They are written in Java, but wrappers to your language may exist:

- [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)
- [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (It's a friendlier version of Apache Lucene, and comes with a pre-built web service along with example documents. Recommended!)